# Save data to memory and after some time save them to DB

Tags: nosql, redis, cassandra, key-value

please accept my apologies in advance because this is probably a stupid question. But...

I am doing some work on a real-time recommender system. There are data like probabilities, rewards and its history in time (by some timestamps or something like that) to be stored. I need to store them firstly in memory and after some time (periodically every one hour) to database (to recover it easily if there occures some server error) so I tried to find some technologies to use and I have found Redis and Cassandra. But I am little bit confused now.

I think there could be this solution:

Store data in RAM (by Redis... more precisly by some Redis client library) and then run some crone which will take these data from memory and store them to some database (probably NoSQL? And which one?)... because I think that I cannot do this straightly with Redis.

Is this approach ok? Or do you have another solution please?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use an *additional* database? Have you checked http://redis.io/topics/persistence?

Comment: I did not check your link before... but it looks interesting. My goal is also a visualisation in time (evolve of probabilities) so I need to have some history by timestamp... I am not sure if this could be achieved by Redis persistence (by some snapshots or AOF)

Comment: You can use timestamps if you convert them to integers and use them in a [Sorted Set](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set). You can then sort by dates etc.

Comment: I see, it could be helpful for me... so as it seems, the best solution will be AOF with some replication by BGREWRITEAOF and write frequency set somewhere in configuration file.. right?

Comment: Whether it's good or not depends on your case. I would just prefer not to add another technology if redis was enough. If it is for you, then yes it sounds nice.

Comment: Agree with @Agis you should see REDIS persistence and also MASTER -SLAVE design model for housekeeping of data.

Comment: @JohnnyGreenwood Added my comments as an answer for others.

Comment: Note on NoSQL are not traditional relational databases they are group of storage alternatives which do not use SQL for data manipulation and maintenance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis *do* provides two persistence options. I strongly recommend to read the [documentation about them](http://redis.io/topics/persistence).

If you want to use the other databases just as backup storage, maybe you are better off by using just what Redis provides you and not adding yet another technology to your stack. In any case you should analyze both and find which one suits you better.

That said, if you need more durability you should probably be better of with *AOF*.